# Anaconda running python: cannot run mkl without a license

Tags: python, interpreter, anaconda, spyder

I'm using Continuum's Anaconda Spyder for python.
All of a sudden it's giving me this error, although it's supposed to be free:

```
Vendor:  Continuum Analytics, Inc.
Package: mkl
Message: trial mode EXPIRED 14 days ago

    You cannot run mkl without a license any longer.
    A license can be purchased it at: http://continuum.io
    We are sorry for any inconveniences.

    SHUTTING DOWN PYTHON INTERPRETER
```

Any idea what the problem might be? I'm using it on Windows 64-bit. I've been using it fine for months. I just got back to it now after some weeks and now it's saying it's expired, but there never was a license as far as I can remember.

Comment: Do you have the Intel Math Kernel Library installed on your machine?

Answer (score 5):

There is a free trial that starts when you `conda install mkl`. If you want to remove it, use `conda remove --features mkl`.

Answer (score 4):

Update as of 5 Feb 2016:

Anaconda now includes an `mkl` package by default, which is in a trial mode unless you get a license. (There is also a free license for personal use.)

To get a license, go to: http://docs.continuum.io/mkl-optimizations/index  and follow the link the "Add Ons"

For details on this change (and instructions on how to remove `mkl` on non-Windows machines), see: https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/anaconda-25-release-now-mkl-optimizations

For Windows you can't remove `mkl` at this time. You can only get a (free) license. (See https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2032#issuecomment-182400140)

Comment: This does not appear to directly answer the question.

Comment: Could you please clarify? I'd be happy to make my answer more direct.

Poster asked what the problem might be, and I gave an updated answer to what could cause that exact problem.

Comment: @EricG. For example, the blog post you linked to does not include removal/disable instructions for Windows (the OPs OS), and `nomkl` is not an available package there.

Comment: Updated answer to provide more Windows OS information.  But original question wasn't asking how to remove it, and it looks you can't remove MKL on Windows :(

Answer (score 0):

The MKL optimizations are not free: https://store.continuum.io/cshop/mkl-optimizations/.

There is a trial period but after that it costs you money. Interesting that you used it for a while. Maybe it's an issue with license checking or there was no mechanism to actually check for a license. When you install the package with `conda install mkl` their is no mention of a license. Maybe something was introduced with a recent version of anaconda?

Comment: is there any math library or anything that I could un-include or something, in order to not use the MKL library?

Comment: You can use the Intel MKL library, just not the ContinuumAnalytics MKL optimizations package for Python (aka `conda install mkl`). With `conda remove mkl` you can remove it. In the end this is just optimization, scipy and numpy work without it.